# Storing Multiple Query results in a single variable

Tags: r, data-structures

I'm running into problem of storing results of multiple queries into a list.
Currently i have the results from previously executed query stored in [a list](http://pastebin.com/YNZUcLej). 
Currently i can't find a way to store the results into a list or anything of that like.

queryResults2 return a 2D list.

```
#Sample code for 2nd select
for(i in length(queryResults[[1]]){
    query_pd <-paste("Select price_date,price from price_master where stock_id ='",queryResults[[1]][i],"' order by price_date")
    queryResults2 <- dbGetQuery(conn, query_pd)
    #storing value here
}
```

Comment: Use `lapply` instead of a `for` loop.

Comment: That was my second concern, but since i had trouble coming up with a way of storing it, wanted to worry about "never using for loops" later. 

The only possible solution using Lapply that i can see is making my own function and passing in the id value and the connection.

Comment: I didn't say "never use `for` loops". If you set them up correctly, there is no problem with using them. A `lapply` loop is just more convenient here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't worry *too* much about the whole "don't use loops" thing. Here are three basic options:

1. `for` loop. The basic template would be:

   ```
   result <- vector("list",length(queryResults[[1]])
   for (i in ...){
       #Do stuff
       result[[i]] <- something
   }
   ```
2. `lapply` Here the basic format would be:

   ```
   lapply(seq_len(queryResults[[1]]),function(i) dbGetQuery(conn,paste(...)))
   ```

   You don't necessarily need the function to take the query and connection object as arguments, R's scoping will be able to find them if they exist in the calling environment.
3. Run it all as one query with an `IN` clause and then `split` is afterwards.

Personally, I try to use (3) as much as possible.

Comment: Thank you, they key part was 
    result <- vector("list",length(queryResults[[1]]))
Whenever i tried it previously it would create lists, but they would be only 1d ones.